# Download File as bytearray using FILE STORAGE AZURE

Tags: c#, php, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-files

What is the PHP equivalente to download a file from Azure with php as a bytearray?
For File storage.
This is done in C# and with blobs:

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = 
cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(targetFileName);
blob.FetchAttributes();
long fileByteLength = blob.Properties.Length;
Byte[] myByteArray = new Byte[fileByteLength];
blob.DownloadToByteArray(myByteArray, 0);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find quite a few examples over here: [Github: Azure/azure-storage-php](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php)

Like this one:

```
function downloadBlobSample($blobClient)
{
    try {
        $getBlobResult = $blobClient->getBlob("mycontainer", "myblob");
    } catch (ServiceException $e) {
        $code = $e->getCode();
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        echo $code.": ".$error_message.PHP_EOL;
    }

    file_put_contents("output.txt", $getBlobResult->getContentStream());
}
```